# java csv semi colon issue

Tags: java, regex, csv, separator

I have to modify a program. This program creates csv file with columns in database like this :

```
    csvBuilder.initCsvFile();
    csvBuilder.createRow(headers.toArray(new String[headers.size()]));
while (resultSet.next()) {
        String[] row = new String[resultSetColumnCount];
        int columnIndex = 1;
        while (columnIndex <= resultSetColumnCount) {
            Object object = resultSet.getObject(columnIndex);
            if (object == null) {
                row[columnIndex - 1] = "";
            } else {
                row[columnIndex - 1] = object.toString();
            }
            columnIndex++;
        }
        csvBuilder.createRow(row);
    }
```

**initCsvFile method**:

```
public void initCsvFile() {
    try {
        writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(filePath), ';', CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("CsvBuilder : error when creating {}", filePath, e);
        throw new CsvException("Error when creating the file : " + filePath, e);
    }
}
```

**createRow method:**

```
public void createRow(String[] row) {
    writer.writeNext(row);
}
```

The problem is that, i have some data that includes the separator ';' like shown below,

```
id col1     col2   
1   US     United;States
```

Unfortunately, the csv file separates United and states in two . How can I check the content of resultSet and escape the separator  without modify all program to get United;states in one row?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I would use a replace() to substitute the ";", if losing it from the original data is not an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In those cases, you will need some quote character, otherwise there will be ambiguity; in your case, you're instructing it to not use quotes, and as a result, it has no way of treating those cases.

Try explicitly defining a quote character:

```
public void initCsvFile() {
    try {
        writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(filePath), ';', '"');
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("CsvBuilder : error when creating {}", filePath, e);
        throw new CsvException("Error when creating the file : " + filePath, e);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, that in this case any data that could cause ambiguity will be enclosed between quotes:

```
1;US;"United;States"
```

That's valid CSV, and most CSV parsers will automatically strip the quotes when reading.

Comment: It's correct but, i get in the csv file ' " ' surrounding each item... I suppose I don't have choice. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

you could replace the ";" before creating csv rows like this

```
while (resultSet.next()) {
        String[] row = new String[resultSetColumnCount];
        int columnIndex = 1;
        while (columnIndex <= resultSetColumnCount) {
            Object object = resultSet.getObject(columnIndex);
            if (object == null) {
                row[columnIndex - 1] = "";
            } else {
                // replace ";" by ""
                row[columnIndex - 1] = object.toString().replace(";", "");
            }
            columnIndex++;
        }
        csvBuilder.createRow(row);
    }
```

Comment: As long as losing those semicolons is not a problem, this could be a good solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't loose semicolons but thank you though

Answer (score 1):

I was just confronted to a similar problem. Apparently, a string is supposed to be escaped with double quotes, to prevent such issues. So I created a `escapeCSVDatum()` function:

```
private static String escapeCSVDatum(String s){
    return "\""+s.replace("\"", "\"\"").replace("\n", " ")+"\"";
}
```

So in your case, it would apply here

```
} else {
    row[columnIndex - 1] = escapeCSVDatum(object.toString());
}
```

However, as stated by Haroldo_OK, your use of `CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER` makes it impossible to treat properly such cases. It is impossible to have a semicolon in a datum with this attribute.

As such, you might want to modify your code to replace semicolons with spaces, like so

```
} else {
    row[columnIndex - 1] = object.toString().replace(";"," ");
}
```

Finally, if you want to mess with people, replace your semicolons with greek question marks.

Comment: For the moment, I can't replace semicolons but thank you :)